# How to activate Azure CDN for cloud service web role

Tags: azure, web, cdn, role

I have created a CDN endpoint at `[id].vo.msecnd.net`, and I have deployed a production mvc4 cloud service web role.

It has images in a root-level `/cdn` folder, but I cannot get those images to load via cdn.  I can access them via direct URL.  For example, this works:

```
[site].cloudapp.net/cdn/eb303.gif
```

but not:

```
[id].vo.msecnd.net/eb303.gif
```

The cdn endpoint is enabled and set up under the hosted service that the web role is in.  The documentation I have been reading indicates that nothing more is required.  I am using a bizspark license, but as far as I can tell that should include CDN endpoints.

Is there a step I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime it may take up to 1 hour before your CDN endpoint is ready to server your content. It  does work with any kind of deployment staging or production.

Do you still have the problem? If you still have the problem you may need to contact Azure Support because if you have enabled the CDN, you should be good to go.

Comment: You're right--I just needed to be more patient.  It took over 3 hours, but it is working fine now.  Thank you!